# Java - copy Jar Folder

Tags: java, android, jar, getresource

Actually I am confronted with a Problem. I've got a ".apk-File" in one Package of my Application. apk is a kind of a jar File (apk = Android Package).
I now want to copy this jar-file out of my Programm onto any other Location at the PC. 
Normally I would do this by using:

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/myApp.apk").getFile());
```

And then write it on the disk with using a FileOutputStream.
... but since an .apk is a kind of a .jar it doesn't work. It just copies the .apk file. but without the containing other files.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.apk` is a `.jar` file by another name (in other words it is a zip file with some specific definitions of where configuration files are stored inside the directory) then look at [ZipInputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) to read the file and walk through the contents and write them out as files.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Yishai... this was the Hint I was waiting for :)
Probably is sb out there, who needs the to do a same thing, therefore... here is my code:

```
public static boolean copyApkFile(File outputFile){
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/myApkFile.apk").getFile());
            ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(fis);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
            ZipEntry ze = null;
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Next entry "+ze.getName()+" "+ze.getSize());
                zos.putNextEntry(ze);
                int len;
                while ((len = zis.read(buf)) > 0) {
                  zos.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
            }
            zos.close();
            fos.close();
            zis.close();
            fis.close();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SetUpNewDevice.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
```